# Why doesn't Ctrl-pgup and Ctrl-pgdn change tabs in vim when started in byobu?

Tags: keyboard, vim, byobu

From what I have read of the documentation, byobu does not use <kbd>Ctrl-pgup</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-pgdn</kbd> for anything, so why is it that when I start `vim -p file1 file2`, and try to move among the different tabs with <kbd>Ctrl-pgup</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-pgdn</kbd>, nothing happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that [Byobu](http://byobu.co) does not capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.  However, in stock Ubuntu, they are actually captured by Gnome Terminal and move among tabs in Gnome Terminal.

You can see this behavior by creating a new tab in Gnome Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>, and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !  I have a follow up: If I have a Gnome Terminal with only one tab, it works as I expected ( that is, vim gets the message and switches between tabs ).  Why is that, and why does Byobu not behave like this ?

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I have reproduced this actually.  This happens, though, with or without Byobu, if you use GNU Screen or Tmux.  It looks like a bug in Screen and Tmux.